# Ada compiler chooses incorrect overloaded function

Tags: ada, gnat

I am using `avr-ada` to compile my program. I want to right shift an `unsigned_16` variable twice. 
`Interfaces.Shift_Right` is overloaded and provides for both `Unsigned_8` and `Unisgned_16`.

When I compile, I get the error 'expected type "Interfaces.Unsigned_8"', 'found type "Interfaces.Unsigned_16"'. I have tried to specify that the input is an `Unsigned_16`, but it won't work. How do I specify the correct function?

```ada
with AVR;                          use AVR;
with AVR.MCU;
with AVR.Timer0;
with AVR.ADC;
with Interfaces;
use Interfaces;
procedure Flash_Led is

   adc_result_10 : Unsigned_16 := 0;
   adc_result_8 : Unsigned_8 := 0;

begin
   -- set OC0A pin as output, required for output toggling
   MCU.DDRD_Bits := (others => DD_Output);
   -- set all pins low
   MCU.PortD := 16#00#;

   -- clear register
   MCU.TCCR0B := 16#00#;

   --  initialize timer to Clear Timer on Compare, scale the input
   --  clock and set a value to compare the timer against.
   Timer0.Init_CTC (Timer0.Scale_By_1024, Overflow => 1);

   --  Toggle the OC0(A)-Pin on compare match
   Timer0.Set_Output_Compare_Mode_Toggle;

   -- Initialize ADC
   ADC.Init(ADC.Scale_By_64, Ref => ADC.Is_Vcc);


   loop   -- loop forever
      adc_result_10 := ADC.Convert_10bit(Ch => 0);
      adc_result_10 := Shift_Right(Unsigned_16'(adc_result_10), 2); --'
      adc_result_8 := Unsigned_8(adc_result_10);
      Timer0.Set_Overflow_At(adc_result_10);
   end loop;
end Flash_Led;
```

Comment: Are you calling `Right_Shift` or `Shift_Right`? Please update your question to show a (small) complete program that illustrates the problem.

Comment: [This](http://pastebin.com/YLWG0ae2) compiles without error for me using GNAT on Linux (referring to an example on pastebin, not the code in the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
Timer0.Set_Overflow_At(adc_result_10);
```

Should have been:

```
Timer0.Set_Overflow_At(adc_result_8);
```

I didn't look at the line number in the error message closely enough. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unsure which function is being called (given that it is overloaded) you can always construct a unique name through renames...

```
function My16_Shift_Right (Item : in Unsigned_16; Amount : Natural) return Unsigned_16 
    renames Interfaces.Shift_Right;
```

and then test the way you are thinking about your program.